# Randomly generating equation and answer

Tags: java, android, random, equation

I am trying to randomly generate an equation that also has a 50% chance of being wrong and displaying that incorrect answer. The incorrect answer should have an error of either -2, -1, +1, or +2.

Sometimes my code prints division equations like this(I can't post images):
2 / 10 = 13
1 / 5 = 43
etc.

I can't figure out why the equation is displaying a mix of numbers that are not checked together?

(It starts with a call to *generateNumbers()* in my *onCreateView* method

```
public void generateNumbers() {
    //randomly generate 2 numbers and an operator
    number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    operator = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    //50% chance whether the displayed answer will be right or wrong
    rightOrWrong = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    //calculate the offset of displayed answer for a wrong equation (Error)
    error = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    generateEquation();
}

public void generateEquation() {
    StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder();
    //append the first number
    equation.append(number1);
    //generate/append the operator and calculate the real answer
    if (operator == 1) {
        equation.append(" + ");
        actualAnswer = number1 + number2;
    } else if (operator == 2) {
        equation.append(" - ");
        actualAnswer = number1 - number2;
    } else if (operator == 3) {
        equation.append(" x ");
        actualAnswer = number1 * number2;
    } else if (operator == 4) {
        if ((number1%number2==0) && (number1>number2)) {
            actualAnswer = number1 / number2;
        } else {
            generateNumbers();
        }
        equation.append(" / ");

    }
    //append the second number and the equals sign
    equation.append(number2 + " = ");

    //we will display the correct answer for the equation
    if (rightOrWrong == 1) {
        displayedAnswer = actualAnswer;
        equation.append(displayedAnswer);
    }
    //we will display an incorrect answer for the equation
    //need to calculate error (-2, -1, +1, +2)
    else {
        if (error == 1) {
            displayedAnswer = actualAnswer - 1;
        } else if (error == 2) {
            displayedAnswer = actualAnswer - 2;
        }else if (error == 3) {
            displayedAnswer = actualAnswer + 1;
        }else {
            displayedAnswer = actualAnswer + 2;
        }
        //append the displayed answer with error
        equation.append(displayedAnswer);

    }
    questionNumber.setText("You have answered " + count + " out of 20 questions");
    finalEquation.setText(equation.toString());
}
```

Comment: There's some weird things in your code.
You generate numbers, then generate equation. Then while generating your equation you generate new numbers if their not suiteable for division, so the generate numbers function is called again. This in turn again calls the generate equation function, but when this finishes, the first call to generate equation continues.

Comment: Yeah I this was what I was thinking when I was trying to solve it, but I went way too in depth and couldn't figure it out. The marked answer solved it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to put a `return` statement after the call to `generateNumbers` in

```
} else if (operator == 4) {
    if ((number1%number2==0) && (number1>number2)) {
        actualAnswer = number1 / number2;
    } else {
        generateNumbers();
    }
    equation.append(" / ");

}
```

since that will restart the whole process, rather than continuing with more numbers.

Comment: Great this works thank you. Don't know how I didn't think of that. Only now I realised the chance of it actually displaying a division equation is pretty low, but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to loose the low chance division problem:

```
public void generateNumbers() {
    number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    //don't get operator here
    //operator = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    rightOrWrong = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    error = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    //don't generate equation here, start (in the View with generateEquation instead of generate numbers
    //generateEquation();
}

public void generateEquation() {
    StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder();
    generateNumbers();

    //determine operator here
    operator = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;


    equation.append(number1);
    if (operator == 1) {
        equation.append(" + ");
        actualAnswer = number1 + number2;
    } else if (operator == 2) {
        equation.append(" - ");
        actualAnswer = number1 - number2;
    } else if (operator == 3) {
        equation.append(" x ");
        actualAnswer = number1 * number2;
    } else if (operator == 4) {
        equation.append(" / ");
        // generate new numbers if they are not suiteable
        while((number1%number2!=0) && (number1<number2))
        {
            generateNumbers();
        }
        actualAnswer = number1 / number2;
    }
    ......
```

Comment: Could probably be better, but I think this will solve the problem.